# Bulk Inserting CSV file to Oracle DB using sqlloader nodeJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, csv

I am trying to load csv file using nodeJS on oracle database.

From documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm it seems to be possible to load the entire csv file and pass on to Oracle by implementing the below.

```
load data
infile 'example.dat'  "str '|\n'"
into table example
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(col1 char(5),
 col2 char(7))
```

where data looks something like

```
hello,world,|
james,bond,|
```

However when I implement it using oracledb library on nodeJS, it throws `ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement` error

The below is how I implement the query.

```
oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user: userId,
        password: password,
        connectString: `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ${host})(PORT = ${port}))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ${sid})))`
    },
    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            errorHandler(err);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute(
            query,
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    errorHandler(err);
                    oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
                    return;
                }

                successHandler(result);
                oracleFunctions.connection.doRelease(connection, errorHandler);
            });
    });
```

my query is as below

```
LOAD DATA
infile 'path\to\the\file.csv' "str '\n'"
INTO TABLE e1_000090000_ADS_R_PPLaps
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the `SQL*Loader` utility, a separate binary provided by Oracle for data loading, with actual valid SQL syntax. You cannot just pass on `SQL*Loader` parameters as SQL statements, they are not! If you want to load a file via Node.js you will have to read the file, parse the contents and translate that to actual `INSERT INTO` statement, which is exactly what `SQL*Loader` does for you.

Comment: Is it really 'exactly' what SQL loader does? Because I hear that it is much faster than just inserts.

Comment: `SQL*Loader` uses a combination of `BULK INSERTS` and [`INSERT APPEND`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Comments.htm#SQLRF50901) to load data, which are indeed much faster than conventional inserts. Both functionalities are part of the database kernel and generally accessible to the user. However, as to Node.js it seems that the driver does not yet support this: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/614

Comment: @gvenzl, do you have any example to use sql loader with oracledb node js.

Comment: As said @AmitKumar, Sql\*Loader is a binary in itself and not a SQL syntax. It therefore can't be used inside Node.js code other than calling the binary. For examples please have a look at the [Sql\*Loader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144).